# building window phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, building

So I've completed a windows phone 7 app and I want to build it and upload it to apphub. I've got 52 images in my app and I'm not sure if theyre included? I've set my build location elsewhere so I know which files are in the build and my images are set to build action content.

When I build my app from Visual Studio is everything needed inluded in my new "build" folder and I just upload all of them or is there something else I need to think about?

Been googling for guides on how to upload for the first time without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All images, that copied into your output directory are unused. You upload only .xap file. To be sure, you could uninstall application from device and than deploy it again through XapDeploy.exe (in SDK folder). If all is good, than you can surely upload .xap to apphub.

Comment: Thanks alot, did not know about XapDeploy that helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of the xap file. It is a simple zip archive, just renamed. Open it (one click in Total Commander, for example) and you'll see everything. Content images are visible immediately.

You can even extract your assembly (i.e. a dll file) and open it in Reflector to see what is included.

Further I recommend that you change the versions in AssemblyInfo.cs with every new release. These versions can then be checked independently, for example in any file manager.